# Manage Step Functions, API Gateway, Lambda through GIT and deploy

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless, aws-step-functions

I am new to writing serverless applications using Step Functions, Lambda, API Gateway.

I have been logging in to AWS console and uploading code manually.

Is there a way for us to manage the code through GIT and Deploy? When I have used EC2, I have always installed SFTP to deploy the code.

Also, I need 3 environments - development, QA and production. What would be the best way of configuring API gateway, Lambda and Step functions to have these 3 separate environments?

Answer (score 1):

You should use CloudFormation and CodePipeline, and possibly CodeBuild. CloudFormation will allow you to create a repeatable template that is used to deploy your resources. CodePipeline is good for managing stages of a deployment (your dev/QA/prod).

Comment: This is the solution if you want to use only official Amazon provided tools and services. In general you want to use Infrastructure as Code, along with a CI/CD pipeline. So for example Terraform and CircleCI would also be a solution.